# How to launch legacy GUI of Clearcase from MSDOS

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have this clear-case tutorial which is based on legacy UI so I wanted to know how to launch Base UI with MSDOS

Comment: What operating system are you using?  What have you tried so far, and what happens when you try it?

Comment: I am using Windows 7,I am working on it for the first time i Saw it for the first time today so not much to try.All I know is I have to launch this :http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21403466

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the base UI is the ClearCase Explorer, then you would type

```
clearexplorer
```

(provided your `%PATH%` include `C:\path\to\rational\clearcase\bin`)

To launch the ClearCase Home base seen in "[Tabs are missing from "ClearCase Home Base" GUI on Microsoft Windows](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21403466)", type:

```
clearhomebase
```

That will launch:

[image: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21403466&aid=1]

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21403466           I need to launch clearcase home base from MS DOS